# ListBox get selected index?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I try to get index of selected item in ListBox:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int index = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
}
```

When I select the second item it returns me index zero again.

Filling ListBox:

```
private void fillWorkListBox()
{
  this.list = manager.works();
  this.listBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
  this.listBox1.ValueMember = "id";

  for (var i = 0; i < this.list.works.Count; i++)
  {
      string name = "№" + this.list.works[i].id + " - " + this.list.works[i].name;

      WorkModel work = new WorkModel();
      work.name = name;
      work.id = this.list.works[i].id;

      listBox1.Items.Add(work);
  }
}
```

Comment: Check in case you have another listBox in your form since the way you made it is right, I can only think there's another ListBox

Comment: Can you show use how you insert/bind the data with the ListBox? Your actual code should be working as intended.

Comment: Yes, edited question

Comment: Any chance you have more than one event handler hooked up?  I'm not seeing anything wrong in the code that you gave us.

Comment: You can try this code replace listBox1.Items.Add(work.name);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your listbox has the SelectionMode property set to something different from the default. For example if the SelectionMode is MultipleSimple then you cannot use the SelectedIndex property because it is not a list of the elements selected. Instead you use the SelectedIndices collection

```
void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    foreach(int x in listBox1.SelectedIndices)
        Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I use multiple. Then how to fix it for multiple?

Comment: If you use multiple then you could have more than one elements selected so you use the SelectedIndices collection, What do you expect to get from the SelectedIndex property. It is always set to the first element selected